# Django - Is it possible to find the mobile device name of users?

Tags: django, mobile, request, user-agent

As the title suggests, is there any way to obtain the mobile device name (like Samsung Galaxy S10) of the client user? The best I have across is - [Django-user_agents](https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents) but it doesn't fetch that information

Comment: i think this might help you (request.user_agent.device)

Comment: Not possible. Browsers don't send this information to server. Even Javascript doesn't have access to this information, so that door is also closed. Most information you can get using is operating system, browser and screen resolution.